# Load values into input value using ngfor

Tags: angular

What I'm trying is to load the multiple values that I'm getting from my database, into the input value field, something like this:

```
 <div *ngIf="items$ | async; let items; else loading">
  <input type="text" size="80" *ngFor="let item of items" value="{{ item.payload.val().Title }}">
  </div>
```

What I would like to accomplish is to have all the values that I'm passing stored into the value field, but to only have one input field where it is all stored.

Comment: And how do you want the values of all elements of this array to be shown in one single `input` field, appearance-wise?

Comment: @amal Appearance-wise it has no importance, I later want to add a button that will play out loud all the titles

Comment: Suppose there are three elements returned with values `'title1', 'title2', 'title3'`. Then how do you want it to look in the input field? Just separated by 1 space char is enough? Like in `title1 title2 title3`

Comment: Yeah 1 space or newline should both be fine

Answer (score 0):

If you understood you correctly, all you want is to simply stack all the relevant values coming from an array into an input.

Something like this should work for you then,

```
<div *ngIf="items$ | async; let items; else loading">
  <input type="text" size="80" [value]="computevalueFromItems(items)">
</div>
```

in component,

```
computevalueFromItems(items: any[]): string {
  return items.reduce((acc, curr, ind, arr) => {
     return (ind === arr.length - 1) ? acc + curr.payload.val().Title : acc + curr.payload.val().Title + ' ';
  }, '');
}
```